# Coding an standalone YouTube Uploader = difficult?

Tags: php, upload, youtube

i saw the YT API and an PHP example how to upload a file.

It's very complex and doesn't just upload the file and some data (title,desc,keys,genre).

It produces a big xml-file or something like that which has to be uploaded before the file itself.

So is it difficult to code a YT Uploader (standalone) in VB or C?

I mean the PHP example needs a big Zend package for this etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Come back here when you have a problem with code you wrote. This kind of question is discouraged here.

Comment: The level of difficulty will depend on many things, including your skill as a programmer, and your familiarity with YouTube uploads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video

Found a sample code written in Python to upload videos (using YouTube Data API). I think this is the best resource you can possibly find and just with a little amount of patience you can fully understand that code and translate it to like PHP.

I suggest you get familiar with that API before trying to understand sample code. It will help you a lot in future.